# Change background colour of specific content between two words using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a Javascript Diff Algorithm designed by John Resig;

http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/#postcomment

I comparing two CSS files and trying to show the differences between them.  Currently I have the comparison side working fine but I want to make some styling changes so that it is easier to read from a user perspective.

I am currently getting the below output in a textarea:

[image]

I want the content between the  tags to be shown in red to represent that it has been deleted in the current file.

Comment: Text area cannot contain rich text unless you use any plugin like ckeditor on that text area.